# Como forçar um clique em um ponto do highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

Tenho uma página que a partir do clique em um ponto do gráfico do highcharts, exibe certos detalhes em uma tabela.

Para certo tipo de perfil do usuário, preciso que estes detalhes sejam exibidos assim que este usuário logar.

Então, gostaria de saber se há como forçar um clique em um ponto do gráfico assim que a página carregar. É possível?

Answer (score 0):

Usa `firePointEvent(type)`, da uma olhada nesse exemplo : http://jsfiddle.net/7xEhW/31/